# Add only all string values of pandas row as list in a new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe:

```
TKDM364             3424.32            3244.39            2724.48            1685.24             0            0
TKDM365             3744.64            3458.03            3132.46            2687.91             0            0
TKDM366             3523.18            4007.76            4487.74            2173.04             0            0
TKDM367             3471.77            3888.26            4032.71            4006.34             0            0
TKDM368   LF_Strut_Pressure  RF_Strut_Pressure  LR_Strut_Pressure  RR_Strut_Pressure             4            0
TKDM369   LF_Strut_Pressure  RF_Strut_Pressure  LR_Strut_Pressure  RR_Strut_Pressure             4            0
TKDM374             3361.51            3384.03            2023.38            2263.13             0            0
TKDM378   LF_Strut_Pressure  RF_Strut_Pressure  LR_Strut_Pressure  RR_Strut_Pressure             4            0
TKDM379             4294.54  RF_Strut_Pressure            4399.79            5525.08             1            1
```

The strange strings that we see in the dataframe, are the column headers. These strings replace NaN values

I want to add a new column to the dataframe that will only add the column names (in string format)  for each row IF the row value in the `last column == 1`.

Expected output: `TKDM379 should show [RF_Strut_Pressure]` in the newly added column.

In other words, IF the value in the current `last column == 1`, THEN add all the string values within this row to a list, and let this list be the value in a new column and same row

PS: The column names were put in place of NaN values (I am new to python and thought this would be a good way of conditionally extract column names if a certain amount of NaN values appear in a row)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do using [`.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) on each row:

```
import string
lets = string.ascii_lowercase

df['new_col'] = (df
                 .apply(lambda x: x[x.apply(lambda z: any([y for y in str(z) if y in lets]))] if x[6] == 1 else [], 
                 axis=1)

                  4  5  6              new_col  
0            1685.24  0  0                   []  
1            2687.91  0  0                   []  
2            2173.04  0  0                   []  
3            4006.34  0  0                   []  
4  RR_Strut_Pressure  4  0                   []  
5  RR_Strut_Pressure  4  0                   []  
6            2263.13  0  0                   []  
7  RR_Strut_Pressure  4  0                   []  
8            5525.08  1  1  [RF_Strut_Pressure]
```

Since you didn't mention the else clause, I am using an empty list. Feel free to change it according to your need.