# add all the values of a row into a new column as a list

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to group together in a new column the values from each row. [Add only all string values of pandas row as list in a new column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59617943/add-only-all-string-values-of-pandas-row-as-list-in-a-new-column) does not work for so I tryed something different which gives a weird result.

here is an example dataset:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'Id' : ['001','002', '003'], 'pred_m1' : [3,2,4], 'pred_m2' : [5,6,4], 'pred_m3' : [6,4,6]})
```

and what I would like is this:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'Id' : ['001','002', '003'], 'pred_list' : [[3,5,6],[2,6,4],[4,4,6]]})
```

I have done this:

```
for i in data:
    data['pred_list'] = list(pd.DataFrame(data['pred_m1'], data['pred_m2'], data['pred_m3']))
    print(data)
```

but its giving me a strange output, and i am not understand what is going wrong

```
    Id  pred_m1  pred_m2  pred_m3  list
0  001        3        5        6     6
1  002        2        6        4     4
2  003        4        4        6     6
    Id  pred_m1  pred_m2  pred_m3  list
0  001        3        5        6     6
1  002        2        6        4     4
2  003        4        4        6     6
    Id  pred_m1  pred_m2  pred_m3  list
0  001        3        5        6     6
1  002        2        6        4     4
2  003        4        4        6     6
    Id  pred_m1  pred_m2  pred_m3  list
0  001        3        5        6     6
1  002        2        6        4     4
2  003        4        4        6     6
```

would anybody have any help on this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `agg` on `axis=1` after setting `Id` column as index and then `reset_index`

```
data.set_index('Id').agg(list,axis=1).reset_index(name='pred_list')
```

---

```
    Id  pred_list
0  001  [3, 5, 6]
1  002  [2, 6, 4]
2  003  [4, 4, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `df.apply()` to group each value in your columns excepting the column "Id":

```
data['pred_list'] = data.apply(lambda row: [val for val in row.drop('Id')], axis=1)
```